# Designing a videogame for android

Tags: android, graphics, animation

I'm trying to develop an RPG for Android, so I need to paint a scenario where i'll move my character.

My idea is to do it 2D. I've developed 3D games and Java games for desktop, but in Android i don't get how to star the scenario.

Coul'd it be developed whith a matrix of information, so I coul'd know where my character steps?

Thank you in advance!